# Output data that is save using esc_js()

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I searched a lot about it and found nothing that much related to my problem. So i post the question.

In wordpress we can save extra data using add_option() function. In my website i made a textarea/ Where i put the google adsence code. When i click on save the data of that area saved to database.

Now if i just get the data and save it in that case its added some extra / or /n in the script. So i used [esc_js()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_js) to save this as code.

Now in other page i need that data and show it there. So i used get_options() and then i echo that. But when i use the get options its actually retiring me the javascript code in encoded(not sure this is the perfect word to express). Here i am putting and example:

```
 If i save "<script></script>"

 its become "&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;  "
```

now how can i get it as it was in the time of save.

My framework is wordpress.

Comment: Can you please show code snippets of where you save it to the database, and where you retrieve it and echo it to your site. Also, please explain in further details why you have to use esc_js() before saving it to the database.

Comment: Have you tried using [html_entity_decode](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)?

Comment: I never know about it. This one works. Can you put it as an answer so that i can close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [html_entity_decode](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).